# dynamic tabs based on json value angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, mat-tab

currently working on material tab where I need to dynamically create tabs based on my json value.

Here is my json

```
[
  {
    "regionName": "EMEA",
    "regionCurrency": "USD",
    "orgnazationName": "XYZ",
    "orgnazationSubName": "Miller"
    "Department": [
      {
        "DepartmentName": "Main",
        "FirstName": "David",
        "LastName": "Brown",
        "Band": 2,
        "Salary": 10000.00
      },
      {
        "DepartmentName": "Main 1", 
        "FirstName": "Marry",
        "LastName": "Brown",
        "Band": 2,
        "Salary": 10000.00
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

the Tab will display like below.  the below tab will take the departmentname

Main    Main 1

This is what I am trying to display I am using material tab

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let item of rowData.Department" label="{{rowData.DepartmentName}}"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

But the tab is not showing in modal whether approach is correct please let me know

Comment: is your `rowData` object similar to json file

Comment: @Sachila yes it is this was similar to my json

Answer (score 0):

looks like the incorrect binding

```
label="{{rowData.DepartmentName}}"
```

should be

```
label="{{item.DepartmentName}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @prabhatojha that's also not coming

Comment: Should you access your json using rowData[0].Department

Answer (score 0):

`rowData` is an array not an object. you need to access the element of the array

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let item of rowData[0].Department" label="{{item.DepartmentName}}"></mat-tab>
```

Comment: when i try to access [0].department I am getting an error as Cannot read property of undefined

Comment: use optioal operator `rowData[0]?.Department`

Comment: DO you get the data for `rowData`. Can you add a console and check